# Why inequalities returns results faster than equalities?

Tags: performance, t-sql, sql-server-2005, querying

In regards to this specific query :

Don't expect to understand the data that is queried : it is irrelevant.

Just take a look at the **WHERE clause** :

```
SELECT 
    de.DocumentEntryId,
    de.Number,
    currentdev.ToIgnore,
    previousdev.ToIgnore,
    currentdev.DocumentEntryValueId AS CurrentDocumentEntryValueId, 
    SUM(currentper.Value) AS CurrentPaymentRate,
    SUM(currentdevr.ConversionRate) AS CurrentConversionRate,
    MAX(previousdev.DocumentEntryValueId) AS PreviousDocumentEntryValueId,
    SUM(previousper.Value) AS PreviousPaymentRate,
    SUM(previousdevr.ConversionRate) AS PreviousConversionRate
FROM 
    DocumentEntry de
    INNER JOIN PaymentEntry currentpe ON currentpe.PaymentEntryId = de.CurrentPaymentEntryId
    INNER JOIN DocumentEntryValue currentdev ON currentpe.DocumentEntryValueId = currentdev.DocumentEntryValueId
    INNER JOIN DocumentEntryValue previousdev ON previousdev.DocumentEntryId = de.DocumentEntryId
    INNER JOIN PaymentEntryRate currentper ON currentpe.PaymentEntryId = currentper.PaymentEntryId
    INNER JOIN DocumentEntryValueRate currentdevr ON currentdev.DocumentEntryValueId = currentdevr.DocumentEntryValueId
    INNER JOIN PaymentEntry previouspe ON previousdev.DocumentEntryValueId = previouspe.DocumentEntryValueId
    INNER JOIN PaymentEntryRate previousper ON previouspe.PaymentEntryId = previousper.PaymentEntryId
    INNER JOIN DocumentEntryValueRate previousdevr ON previousdevr.DocumentEntryValueId = previousdev.DocumentEntryValueId
WHERE 
    previousdev.DocumentEntryValueId <> currentdev.DocumentEntryValueId
    AND currentdev.ToIgnore <> 1
    AND previousdev.ToIgnore <> 1
    AND currentpe.PaymentId = previouspe.PaymentId
GROUP BY 
    de.DocumentEntryId, 
    de.Number,
    currentdev.ToIgnore,
    previousdev.ToIgnore,
    currentdev.DocumentEntryValueId
ORDER BY DocumentEntryId
```

Especially these two **inequalities** :

```
AND currentdev.ToIgnore <> 1
AND previousdev.ToIgnore <> 1
```

**Note** : ToIgnore is a bit column.

This query takes around 10 seconds to return about 1300 rows.

However, if I change these two lines to use the **equality** operator :

```
AND currentdev.ToIgnore = 0
AND previousdev.ToIgnore = 0
```

It takes forever to return anything.

It it helps, here are the indexes from each table :

Table **DocumentEntry** indexes :

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DocumentEntry] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DocumentEntry$0] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [DocumentEntryId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [Data Filegroup 1]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_DOCUMENTENTRY_REFNUMBER] ON [dbo].[DocumentEntry]
(
    [EntryReferenceNumber] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [Data Filegroup 1]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [missing_index_14227] ON [dbo].[DocumentEntry]
(
    [MasterDocumentEntryId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [Data Filegroup 1]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [missing_index_186297_186296_DocumentEntry] ON [dbo].[DocumentEntry]
(
    [Number] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [DocumentEntryId]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [Data Filegroup 1]
```

Table **DocumentEntryValue** indexes :

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DocumentEntryValue] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DocumentEntryValue$0] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [DocumentEntryValueId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [Data Filegroup 1]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_DOCUMENTENTRYVALUE_DOCENTRYID] ON [dbo].[DocumentEntryValue]
(
    [DocumentEntryId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [Data Filegroup 1]


CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_DOCUMENTENTRYVALUE_REFNUMBER] ON [dbo].[DocumentEntryValue]
(
    [EntryValueReferenceNumber] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [Data Filegroup 1]


CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [missing_index_4022_4021_DocumentEntryValue] ON [dbo].[DocumentEntryValue]
(
    [ReferenceDocumentId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [Data Filegroup 1]
```

Table **DocumentEntryValueRate** indexes :

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DocumentEntryValueRate] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DocumentEntryValueRate$0] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [DocumentEntryValueRateId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [Data Filegroup 1]


CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [missing_index_56865_56864_DocumentEntryValueRate] ON [dbo].[DocumentEntryValueRate]
(
    [DocumentEntryValueId] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [timestamp],
    [DocumentEntryValueRateId],
    [RateId],
    [RateVersionId],
    [RateTypeId],
    [RateGroupId],
    [RatePeriodValueId],
    [ConversionRate]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [Data Filegroup 1]
```

Table **PaymentEntry** indexes :

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PaymentEntry] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PaymentEntry$0] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PaymentEntryId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [Data Filegroup 1]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_PAYMENTENTRY_DOCENTRYVALUEID] ON [dbo].[PaymentEntry]
(
    [DocumentEntryValueId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [Data Filegroup 1]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [missing_index_2517_2516_PaymentEntry] ON [dbo].[PaymentEntry]
(
    [PaymentId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [Data Filegroup 1]
```

Table **PaymentEntryRate** indexes :

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PaymentEntryRate] ADD  CONSTRAINT [PaymentEntryRate$0] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PaymentEntryRateId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [Data Filegroup 1]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_PAYMENTENTRYRATE_PAYMENTENTRYID] ON [dbo].[PaymentEntryRate]
(
    [PaymentEntryId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [Data Filegroup 1]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [missing_index_2618_2617_PaymentEntryRate] ON [dbo].[PaymentEntryRate]
(
    [RateId] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [timestamp],
    [PaymentEntryRateId],
    [PaymentEntryId],
    [RateTypeId],
    [RateGroupId],
    [RateVersionId],
    [RatePeriodValueId],
    [Value]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [Data Filegroup 1]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [missing_index_2686_2685_PaymentEntryRate] ON [dbo].[PaymentEntryRate]
(
    [RateTypeId] ASC,
    [RateId] ASC,
    [RatePeriodValueId] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [PaymentEntryId]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [Data Filegroup 1]
```

Here is a part of the estimated execution plan when I use the equality operators (= 0) :
[image: Estimated execution plan]

Can someone explains why, in this case (or probably in many cases), the inequality operator seems faster than the equality operator ?

Comment: Have you compared the actual execution plans for the two queries for clues?

Comment: I can get the execution plan from the inequality query, but the equality query just runs forever ...

Comment: Remember that bit fields have three states, not two.

Comment: Are you using indices? If so, could you post any relevant indices you may have on the tables in the query above?

Comment: @Cory, thank you very much for your time on this. I am a total beginner with SQL : Is there any query I can write to query the implicated table's indices that would return relevant information as a query result ?

Comment: In SSMS, in the tree-view for a table, there is an "Indexes" folder. If you expand that, you will see all the indexes (if any). Assuming there are only a few, you can right-click on the index, choose "Script Index As" > "CREATE To" > "Clipboard"; then paste the generated SQL into your question as an edit (just include the main index definition).

Comment: @Cory I updated my answer with the index definitions from each table. I have noticed there are many of them, and the "missing_index_*" ones seemed to have been created from an optimizing tool. Maybe you know what it is ?

Comment: @SteveHémond: It's a bit alarming that there is no index that includes the `ToIgnore` column whatsoever.  Seems to me that there should be one that combines `DocumentEntryValue.DocumentEntryValueId` and `DcoumentEntryValue.ToIgnore`. If you view the estimated or actual query plan for the query that works, does it suggest any additional missing indices? (Will show up as green text at the top of the execution plan.)

Comment: @Cory, I see no green text at the top of the execution plan. Is there a way I can show the execution plan in my answer ? Exporting in as XML generates a quite huge file.

Comment: Are there suggested indexes if you get an estimated execution plan for the query that doesn't finish? (Highlight SQL, click the "Display Estimated Execution Plan" button next to the blue checkmark in the toolbar.) It would be painful for me to write you an index without being on your machine to see what happens -- there's only so much I can do through [so].

Comment: I have updated my answer to show you what is returned on the estimated execution plan of the neverending query. It's only a part, but it is to show you that no index is suggested.

Comment: Can you see any obvious differences between the two query plans?

Comment: There a differences at the beginning : it doesn't query the same indexes, BUT, there is 0% cost until the very end of the query plan. The end of the query plan are very similar ; only the costs are different. What I don't understand is the overall cost is mostly the same. I cannot understand why the "inequalities query" runs forever when I look at the query plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but I'm unable to post comments, only answers so please ignore if this doesn't work for you.

Creating a nonclustered index with "WHERE ToIgnore = 0" should correct the issue.

What is the record count for records with ToIgnore=1 vs ToIgnore=0?  My guess is the amount of records with ToIngore=1 is much larger than them being set to 0.

I remember a while back an Oracle/SQL DBA telling me that and index was not needed for bit columns because Microsoft took care of that for you, which would explain your problem.  However, I'm unable to find anything to back it up and it might be something with Oracle and they assumed MS must do it as well.

Comment: It's the opposite : 
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DocumentEntryValue WHERE ToIgnore = 0 returns 288123 rows.

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DocumentEntryValue WHERE ToIgnore = 1 returns 217 rows.

Comment: I'm attempting to run the same scenerio, but I'm 12 minutes into inserting 288000 records in a table.  :/

Comment: ok, I created a table, added 288000 records with 1 as the ToIgnore field.   Added another 240 record with 0 as the ToIgnore field.   This table has zero indexes.   No matter how I run it, it's alway the same in timing.  I looked at the Execution plan it always does a 100% table scan for either way.    I looked up Operator Precedence in hopes to find some kind of order of operation difference between <> and = and they are the same.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx  My guess, may be an index issue and MS is evaluating the query different based on your small change.

Comment: thank you so much for your time on this. I think that there is nothing else anybody can do for this problem because of the data structure (and the data) that cannot be reproduced by others. As you all said, this is probably an index issue that I will investigate in a near future. I will mark your post as answered. Thanks again !